# Circular array slicing

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array with a varying number of elements 0..n elements. An example could be:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

In an iterative process, I would like to move a cursor in the array and slice out a max number of elements. If I reach the "end" of the array, it should start over and pick from the beginning again:

Something like this:

```
4.times do |i|
  a.slice(i * 3, 3)
end
# i = 0 => [0,1,2]
# i = 1 => [3,4,5]
# i = 2 => [6,7,8]
# i = 3 => [9,0,1]
# ...
```

However the last output `i = 3` produces `[9]` as `.slice` does not do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle):

```
a.cycle.each_slice(3).take(4)
#=> [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: exactly what I had in mind - `a.cycle.each_slice(3).take(4).map.with_index {|a,i| "i = #{i} => #{a}"}`, but was not sure if that's what needed from the question :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko the example contains the expected output: `i = 3 => [9,0,1]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Array#rotate](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/rotate), and then take the first 3 elements each time:

```
4.times.each { |i| a.rotate(i*3)[0..2] }
# => [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
4.times { |i| p a.values_at(*(i*3..i*3+2).map {|e| e % 10 }) }
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9, 0, 1]
```

9%10 = 9, 10%10 = 0, 11%10 = 1. So you will get the desired output.

Comment: Note that the question has a `ruby` tag.

Comment: same concept applies though, no?

Answer (score 0):

This might break some code, so be careful.

```
class Array
  alias_method :old_slice, :slice
  def slice(o, c)
     ret = old_slice(o % size, c)
     if ret.size != c
        ret += old_slice(0, c - ret.size)
     end
     ret
  end
end

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

4.times do |i|
  p a.slice(i * 3, 3)
end
```

As Stephan points out it would be better to give this method a different name, or it might be even better to create a CircularArray class.

```
class CircularArray < Array
  alias_method :straight_slice, :slice
  def slice(o, c)
     ret = straight_slice(o % size, c)
     if ret.size != c
        ret += straight_slice(0, c - ret.size)
     end
     ret
  end
end
```

Comment: Just give _your_ method another name, there's absolutely no need to rename the built-in one.